# Angular7 Ngrx6 withLatestFrom warning

Tags: angular, ngrx, rxjs6

I am having an issue when using withLatestFrom. The console is showing the following error:

*You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable*

The code is:

```
import { first, map, distinctUntilChanged, withLatestFrom } from 'rxjs/operators';

    this.subscriptionList.push(
        this.store
            .select(fromReducer.getSelectedProduct)
            .pipe(withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromReducer.getAllUrlConfigurationEntities)))
            .pipe(
                map(([product, urlConfigurations]) => {
                    const my_product = product || {};
                    return {
                        urlConfigurations,
                        product: my_product
                    };
                }),
                distinctUntilChanged((previous: any, current: any) => current.urlConfigurations.length === 0 || previous.product.id === current.product.id)
            )
            .subscribe(data => {
                const urlConfigurations = data.urlConfigurations;
                console.log(urlConfigurations);
                if (urlConfigurations) {
                    this.urlConfigurations = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(urlConfigurations));
                }

                return;
            })
    );
```

I tried returning an observable like `.pipe(withLatestFrom(this.store.select(fromReducer.getAllUrlConfigurationEntities)))`.

But I need the value afterwards and not the Observable.

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Make sure you are importing from the correct Rxjs module, and not from the internals.

Comment: Where I am lost is all example I saw are importing the operators has follow:
import { first, map, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';

Comment: Yeah that's correct.

Comment: It's what I tried but still getting this error. To be noted as I got this as soon as I update from rxjs 5 to 6.

Comment: Thank you @cgTag. I was able to make it working by changing the import of combineLatest to use the rxjs one and not the operator one.

Old Code
```javascript
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Working version for my use case
```javascript
import {combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```

Comment: Yeah. Impossible to connect this error message with that solution. Only experience will help. I really wish they packaged the library better than this.

Comment: You should post this as the answer. So others can find it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `createSelector` selector and not the `getter` from the reducer.